# how to edit column value before binding to gridview after retriving from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

After i retrieved a set of datatable from database, i need to edit the rows value before binding to the gridview.
for example, a set of datatable is retrived from database.

eg: [userid], [userEmail]  --> 1 , james@hotmail.com

i would like to change "james@hotmail.com" to "james" then bind it to gridview. 
Every rows of [userEmail] will be separated with the mail extension (@hotmail.com) ...
how should i do..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
DataTable dt = getMyDataTable();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
     string email = Convert.ToString(dr["email"]);
     email = email.Substring(0, email.IndexOf('@'));
     dr["email"] = email;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tap into the DataBound Event of the GridView and edit the userEmail value.

Something like this :

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // format the email, provided cell 1 is email
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = e.Row.Cells[1].Text.Substring(0, e.Row.Cells[1].Text.IndexOf("@"));
    }
}
```

In your ASPX file :

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
    datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
    onrowdatabound="CustomersGridView_RowDataBound"
    runat="server">
</asp:gridview>
```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx